# robocopy only copy recent files, not recent folders

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I had to create a copy of the file structure from a fileshare using `robocopy C:\something D:\something /E /EF *.*` I now just have all the folders, no files. Now, I just want to `robocopy` files that were updated in the past X days. The problem is the folders have a recently modified date and I don't want to copy all their contents, especially root folders. I just want to copy the FILES that have changed to their matching destination directory.

I can't seem to find anywhere where I can ONLY have it copy files and disregard the folders that have recent modified dates. Example: `C:\something` shows a recently modified date, `C:\something\something\something\this.txt` is the only thing I want to copy, not have it try to copy C:\something and all of it's subfolders. The destination should only contain the `this.txt`.

Eventually I want to run a `robocopy` with `/MINAGE` and only copy files modified after X to the destination.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something called CopyWhiz. It has this functionality built in and can create directory structure on source.